# Does API level 8 support is going to finish up in coming days.?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, build-tools, android-api-levels

I have Updated my Android Studio to 2.2.2 and installed Latest SDK.
Now Build tools version is 25.0.0, but when I tried creating a new project, in minimum SDK section there is no API level 8 (Froyo) option.

Also I tried importing my project which having minSdkVersion 8, but it is giving me the error : "uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0]" and it suggest me to use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

So does it mean, from now on the latest appCompat-v7 will no longer support API 8?
I know I can develop for the API 8 using lower versions of appCompat-v7 and build tools but isn't there any way to use this latest library(s) for API 8 (without overriding appCompat-v7:25.0.0).

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support libraries since the version of **24.2.0** moved the **minSdk to 9**.

You can check the official [release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html):

> Note: **Release 24.2.0 removes support for Android 2.2 (API level 8) and lower**. Classes and methods that exist only to serve those system versions are now marked as deprecated and should no longer be used. These deprecated classes and methods may be removed in a future release

About your question:

> So does it mean, from now on the latest appCompat-v7 will no longer support API 8?

Yes, these libraries will not support this api level.
If you want to work with minSdk=8 you have to use the version **24.1.1**.

Comment: A valid reason to stick on Eclipse.

Comment: @Rotwang it is not related to the IDE. I can understand your point.Also in eclipse the support libraries v24.2.0 + will support only minSdk = 9.

Comment: Thanks for the info Man!, I checked the link you provided.. but i cant find the line "Release 24.2.0 removes support for Android 2.2 (API level 8) and lower" there, could you please tell where they mentioned this.?

Comment: @MaheshB Check the "Android Support Library, revision 24.2.0" paragraph and expand it.

Comment: @Gabriele I found it thanks..! I think API 8 support is going to end up all the way in future..

Answer (score 0):

yes definitely the updates are to improvize the configuration and with some new updates the old sdk versions will not be compatible . check out for example vector assets in android studio which are not compatible with older sdk's

try using this dependency in your project and compile
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

also in your application class write
this.install(multidex);

try it out .it may work

Comment: `check out for example vector assets ... which are not compatible with older sdk's` So what are the **support libraries** for, in your opinion?

Comment: that support libraries helps you sometimes when your sdk version gets incompatible

Comment: `support libraries helps you sometimes` I.e.: when you need VectorDrawables on older API Levels.